# How to empty trash on hadoop when namespace quota is exceeded?

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-spark, command-line, hdfs

I want to start a hadoop streaming job, but it fails complaining:
`15/05/19 23:17:34 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : The NameSpace quota (directories and files) of directory /user/myname is exceeded: quota=1000000 file count=1000001`

I tried deleting some files using `hdfs dfs -rm -r -f files` which reports that files are moved to trash. I then tried `hdfs dfs -expunge` and I get back:

`15/05/19 23:12:32 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion interval = 0 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
15/05/19 23:12:33 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Created trash checkpoint: /user/myname/.Trash/150519231233`

But I still get the original error. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would follow the other answer...

---

If you *really know what you are doing*, then you could do:

```
[gsamaras@gwta3000 ~]$ hadoop fs -rm -f -r -skipTrash /path/to/dirToBeDeleted
Deleted /path/to/dirToBeDeleted
```

which I assembled after reading: [How to delete a non-empty directory in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217893/how-to-delete-a-non-empty-directory-in-terminal) and the rest..

---

When you delete a file or a directory, it goes into Trash, but when you delete Trash, there is an interval (that is configurable and depends on your setup, mine's is 1h), which has to pass by, so that the actual deletion occurs.

The idea is that you might delete something important (or something generated after much computing power is used) by accident and that configuration gives you the opportunity to recover your data.

If you are not sure how to proceed, then I would advice to wait for at least an hour and then try again, otherwise..

---

From that [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6080), there is this list that proposes some ideas:

1. Tell users to use `-Dfs.trash.interval=0` when deleting large
   directory
2. Exclude `/user/<username>/.Trash` from the quota
3. Move `.Trash` out of `/user directory`. Maybe `/Trash/<username>`
   and set different quota.
4. When `-rm`/`rmr` fail with quota, automatically delete them.
5. Introduce a separate command that does (1). Something like `-rmr
   -skipTrash` for force delete.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I only needed to wait some hours, until everything settles down!

Comment: I meant to say that I see no upvote, thus I am worried...BTW, what you say is also true, that's why I upvoted..

Comment: I did not upvote because I am no longer in a state to test what you said. ;-)

Comment: Oh OK Mahdi. I am sure it works though, so we are cool, but I like your style, keep it up!